# select cells from an excel table python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, select

i have a an excel table that contains :

| ID product | 03/1/2021 | 16/1/2022 | 12/2/2022 | 14/3/2023 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 4 | 1 | 2 | 5 |
| B | 6 | 1 | 3 |  |
| C |  | 7 |  | 6 |

and in the same sheet I have a drop down list that contains(the year , and the month)

[image]

- if i select in the drop down list for example year = 2020 and month= 1,

it will be return something like this:

| ID product | 03/1/2021 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 4 |
| B | 6 |
| C |  |

and then it will calculate the som of the cells : som = 10 in this case

here is my code :

```
# import load_workbook
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation import DataValidation
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill

# set file path
filepath= r'test.xlsx'

wb=load_workbook(filepath)
ws=wb["sheet1"]


#Generates 10 year in the Column MK;
for number in range(1,10): 
    ws['MK{}'.format(number)].value= "202{}".format(number)
    
data_val = DataValidation(type="list",formula1='=MK1:MK10') 
ws.add_data_validation(data_val)

# drop down list with all the values from the column MK
data_val.add(ws["E2"]) 

#Generates the numbers of month in the Column MN;
for numbers in range(1,12): 
    ws['MN{}'.format(numbers)].value= "{}".format(numbers)
    

data_vals = DataValidation(type="list",formula1='=MN1:MN14') 
ws.add_data_validation(data_vals)


# drop down list with all the values from the sheet list column MK
data_vals.add(ws["E3"]) 
      
# add a color to the cell 'year' and 'month'
ws['E2'].fill = PatternFill(start_color='FFFFFF00', end_color='FFFFFF00', fill_type = 'solid')
ws['E3'].fill = PatternFill(start_color='FFFFFF00', end_color='FFFFFF00', fill_type = 'solid')


# save workbook
wb.save(filepath)
```

Any suggestions?

thank you for your help.

Comment: What is your question? What does this have to do with Python? Also where is some code, like [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: my question is to have a code in python that allows to filter automatically the columns , and calculate the sum of the rows for the column chosen . I don't know if it's clear ? I dont' have the code but I can descibe it like this :   if (the year and the month in the dropdown list ) isin the columns of the table ,  then selects those columns and calculate the som of the rows

Comment: Please, upload at least a part of code where you load the data from Excel or CSV file to Python. For example to pandas DataFrame. Then we can move from there.

Comment: ok I will do we it right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your excel file looks like below:

[image]

---

**Final Code** looks like below:

```
import xlrd
file = r'C:\path\test_exl.xlsx'
sheetname='Sheet1'
n=2
df = pd.read_excel(file,skiprows=[*range(2)],index_col=[0])

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file)
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name(sheetname)
year = worksheet.cell(0,0).value
month = worksheet.cell(1,0).value

datetime_cols= pd.to_datetime(df.columns,dayfirst=True,errors='coerce')
out = (df.loc[:,(datetime_cols.year == year) & (datetime_cols.month == month)]
       .reset_index())
```

---

```
print(out)

  ID Product  03-01-2021
0          A         4.0
1          B         6.0
2          C         NaN
```

---

**Breakdown:**

you can first read the table in pandas using `pd.read_excel`:

```
file = r'C:\path\test_exl.xlsx'
sheetname='Sheet1'
n=2 #change n to how many lines to skip to read the table. 
#In the above image my dataframe starts at line 3 onwards so I put n=2

df = pd.read_excel(file,skiprows=[*range(n)],index_col=[0])
```

Then access the cell values using `xlrd`:

```
import xlrd
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file)
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name(sheetname)
year = worksheet.cell(0,0).value #A1 is 0,0
month = worksheet.cell(1,0).value #A2 is 1,0 and so on..
#print(year,month) gives 2021 and 1
```

then convert columns to datetime and filter:

```
datetime_cols= pd.to_datetime(df.columns,dayfirst=True,errors='coerce')
out = (df.loc[:,(datetime_cols.year == year) & (datetime_cols.month == month)]
      .reset_index())
```

Comment: Yes! this is the results i want to have, just a question if i want to have the same table format after the results, the filter will still be there so i can choose another year and another month.

Comment: @FaziaChenna Your question is about writing back to excel with the data validation retained ?? . I am not sure about the that. May be that qualifies as a separate question. If this question is answered, consider accepting/upvoting the solution.

Comment: @FaziaChenna May be you can take a look at [this](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_data_validation.html)